# JavaScript with parameters not being called from code behind

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

Hello I'm still pretty new to JavaScript and I am trying to call a function with multiple parameters from the codebehind. I believe I am calling it wrong because I cant even hit the degubber on my javascript file. The function is supposed to take those parameters and set the textboxes and such to those values.

Here is my codebehind:

```
RadScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), Guid.NewGuid().ToString(), "createEditAccount('" + ar2.Received_Date +"','" + ar2.Deposited_Date + "','" +
                                    ar2.Company_Name + "','" + ar2.Check_Amount + "','" + ar2.Check_Number + "','" +
                                    ar2.Description_ + "','" + arb.Breakdown_Amount  +
                                     "','" + arb.Account_Number + "','" + arb.Breakdown_Amount + "','" + arb.Notes + ");", true);
```

Here is my JavaScript Function:

```
function createEditAccount(ReceivedDate, DepositedDate, tbCompanyName, tbCheckAmount, tbCheckNum, tbDesc, cbResultsBreak, cbResultAcctNum, tbResultBreak, tbResultNotes) {
$("#EditAccount").modal('toggle');
$telerik.findControl(document, "ReceiveDate").value = ReceivedDate;
$telerik.findControl(document, "DepositDate").value = DepositedDate;
$telerik.findControl(document, "tbCompanyName").value = tbCompanyName;
$telerik.findControl(document, "tbCheckAmount").value = tbCheckAmount;
$telerik.findControl(document, "tbCheckNum").value = tbCheckNum;
$telerik.findControl(document, "tbDesc").value = tbDesc;
$telerik.findControl(document, "cbResultsBreak").value = cbResultsBreak;
$telerik.findControl(document, "cbResultAcctNum").value = cbResultAcctNum;
$telerik.findControl(document, "tbResultBreak").value = tbResultBreak;
$telerik.findControl(document, "tbResultNotes").value = tbResultNotes;
$("#MainContent_subType").val("new");
```

}

Comment: RadScriptManager... that's a Telerik control, right? Consider tagging that in your question.

Comment: Have you tried ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock ... it depends where in the page life cycle you are trying to call the js function.

Comment: I am attemping to call the javascript function from a row click on a RadGrid.

Comment: I have tried using an asp:ScriptManager with no luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was that I needed to use the `ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock()` because I'm working with a modal and this method is for ajax postbacks.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass an additional parameter to the RegisterClientStartupScript method call to indicate that scriptTags need to be added.

```
Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(
    GetType(), 
    "MyKey", 
    "Myfunction();", 
    true);
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I believe I already have this. It is the bool at the end correct?